# How do I get JavaScript Intellisense from vsdoc file references in WebMatrix 2 Beta?

Tags: webmatrix, javascript-intellisense

I copied a JavaScript file over from Visual Studio to a new WebMatrix 2 Beta project only to find out the vsdoc file wasn't being used for JavaScript Intellisense.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" />
```

JavaScript's core functions do show up in Intellisense, but it doesn't appear to pull additional data from vsdoc files.

#### Spoiler alert: I will be answering this myself to bring the answer from its current [webmatrix.uservoice.com location](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/2308591-support-javascript-intellisense-through-vsdoc-file) to StackOverflow for anyone else with this issue. [Please don't take offense to this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since they are currently [taking user input on desired features in WebMatrix 2 Beta](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/), I pitched support  for vsdoc JavaScript file references. The WebMatrix team responded that it was already supported but the syntax was different until [they change it to be more consistent with the current Visual Studio syntax](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/2308591-support-javascript-intellisense-through-vsdoc-file). It is only different by one word.

#### Works in WebMatrix 2 Beta (note "file" instead of "path")

```
/// <reference file="jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" />
```

[image]

#### Note:

While the "path" syntax doesn't work in WebMatrix 2 Beta yet, the WebMatrix team seemed intent on supporting it going forward for consistency with Visual Studio. If, for some reason, someone is using the same *vsdoc.js file between a WebMatrix 2 Beta project and a Visual Studio project (or managing a a WebMatrix user's project in Visual Studio), you could simply cover both bases. The WebMatrix "file" syntax does not appear to be supported by Visual Studio 2010.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference file="jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" />
```

#### Additional Note:

WebMatrix 2 Beta does not appear to support the new paragraph-sectioned (`<para>`) vsdoc files.