# Loading jQuery VSDoc in WebMatrix

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, webmatrix, javascript-intellisense

Quick question here.  I'm trying to get jQuery intellisense in WebMatrix 2 Beta using the CDN.  I create a blank .js file with the following line (note WebMatrix 2 Beta uses "file" instead of "path"):

```
/// <reference file="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" />
```

but nothing happens.  I'll type the `$` sign expecting it to show up in Intellisense, but I only get the built-in Javascript intellisense and nothing related to jQuery.  I've tried adding a reference to jQuery itself, like so:

```
/// <reference file="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
```

and still nothing.

I have the same thing happen in Visual Studio (2008 SP1) and Visual Web Developer Express 2010; I've tried updating the Javascript intellisense and although it refreshes, nothing changes.  Every example of getting the Intellisense seems to indicate this is all that I need to do.

What am I missing to get jQuery Intellisense?

Comment: Just in case it helps: edit > view > update jscript intellisense.

Comment: Seems to fix it in VWD but there's no option to update Intellisense that I can find for WebMatrix.

Comment: Hi WayneM you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7742324/141022

It looks as though it should be supported, but webmatrix beta 2 at the moment requires a slightly different format.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, those reference tags will only work for JavaScript files that are stored locally inside of your project.  We know this is a problem, and it's something we're looking to add.  If you're interested in voting to have this implemented, we would love to have you enter an issue on uservoice:

http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/

Happy Coding!