# how to add jQuery intellisence to webmatrix 2 beta php file?

Tags: php, jquery, webmatrix

i want to create a php site using WebMatrix 2.0 beta.
i want to add some jQuery functions but using its intellisence (i heard thats possibke).

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz see this: http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/2308591-support-javascript-intellisense-through-vsdoc-file **or** http://forums.asp.net/t/1729245.aspx/1

**vsdoc** files is the magic you are looking for:

With Intellisense already there for JavaScript, it would be great to be able to extend it with references to additional vsdoc files.

And a very good read here: [How do I get JavaScript Intellisense from vsdoc file references in WebMatrix 2 Beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742313/how-do-i-get-javascript-intellisense-from-vsdoc-file-references-in-webmatrix-2-b),

Hope this helps, and provide you enough information`:)`

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" />
```